# How to wrap methods with similar stuff(example with hibernate)

Tags: java, methods

So, I am coding my hibernate-jpa helloworlds here, and run into the copypaste problem: every operation contains same "wraps": initialization of similar variables, similar try/catch/finally block, etc. And couple lines of distinct useful code. Now this is not the first time I ran into such copypaste bacchanalia, and it gets to me. Here's some methods:

```
private Integer addEmployeeToDB(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
    //similar:
    EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = manager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();

        //here is useful part
        Employee employee = new Employee(fname, lname, salary);
        manager.persist(employee);
        //end of useful part. similar again:

        transaction.commit();
        return employee.getId();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (transaction != null) transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

and

```
private void deleteEmployee(Integer code) {
    EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = manager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();

        //useful part:
        Employee employee = manager.find(Employee.class, code);
        manager.remove(employee);

        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (transaction != null) transaction.rollback();
    }
}
```

Now, I know that I can make a Listener(or Runnable?) to wrap some code in try/catch. But firstly, that is now very pretty, and secondly, just not enough: I want all similarities in wrap, and 2 lines of code to be actually 2-3 lines.

Delegating methods via String, like:

method 1 is called - redirects to method 2 and passes a string

method 2 has a switch-case inside all the wrap, and by passed string(with name of method 1) chooses what to do

is also a bad solution, I think. Too hardcoded.

So, is there a nice way to do it? And if not, what are closest options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As exception management of queries take a lot of work to get right I try to peel out that into an abstract super class and use that to fill in the inner functionality.

```
abstract class TransactionalQuery {

    void execute() {
        EntityManager manager = createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = manager.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            // Do my transaction.
            transaction(manager);

            transaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void transaction(EntityManager manager);
}

private void deleteEmployee(Integer code) {
    new TransactionalQuery() {
        @Override
        protected void transaction(EntityManager manager) {
            //useful part:
            Employee employee = manager.find(Employee.class, code);
            manager.remove(employee);
        }
    }.execute();
}

private Integer addEmployeeToDB(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
    // Using an AtomicInteger as a Mutable Integer - not good practice.
    final AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger();
    new TransactionalQuery() {
        @Override
        protected void transaction(EntityManager manager) {
            //here is useful part
            Employee employee = new Employee(fname, lname, salary);
            manager.persist(employee);
            id.set(employee.getId());
        }
    }.execute();
    return id.get();
}
```

Comment: Neat! Just what I needed, will work everywhere and with everything I think. Thanks. Why is this thing not-so-common?

Comment: @JollyRoger - Because some currently feel that using callbacks (of which this is an example) is an antipattern. I disagree, I feel it is only *sometimes* an antipattern.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Google only tells me about JS antipattern. Could you provide a link/example where this is an antipattern?

Comment: @JollyRoger - Google "Callback Hell". [Here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-callback-hell) is a reasonable description of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the first method, instead of passing all the parameters, make it accept an `Entity`, a `super type` they all inherit from

```
interface Entity{
  Integer getId();
}

class Employee implements Entity{
 ...
}
```

And now you can have a method that persists an `Entity`

```
private Integer persistEntity(Entity entity) {
 ...
 manager.persist(entity);
 ...
 transaction.commit();
 return entity.getId();
 ..
}
```

Now for deleting the entity, this requires passing the `type` to the `manager`, which is easily achievable with `generics`

```
private void deleteEntity(Integer id, Class<? extends Entity> clazz) {
  .. 
  Entity e = manager.find(clazz, id);
  manager.remove(e);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. When there will be not helloworlds, I'll do so.

Comment: However, that doesn't solve entire problem, just a perculiar case. For instance, I have a project with jdbc and not hibernate, and there's a resembling wrapper: initialize-nulls Connection and Statement, then in try block some useful operations, then catch and finally with closures. Or can this be solved similarly?

Comment: Yes, you can solve it in a similar way, it might be a good exercise for you :) Or you can use a library; Spring jdbc comes to mind

Comment: Errr looks like nope. This approach can unify one operation for many entities, which is cool, but I need different operations for one(maybe for many, but later) entity. And operations in that project differ also. Voting you up, but no answer for request still. Edit: not voting, insufficent rep:)

Comment: @JollyRoger note that I don't know anything about your final goal, I am trying to help you solving a problem you demonstrated in your post.

Comment: I know. But again, in the post there are two methods(assume that there are simply 'many') that operate over one entity, and problem is squeezing down those via supplementary method or something else. You demonstrated ohter thing: how to make methods appliable for any entity. Very useful in particular case, but not exactly to the point.

Comment: Got the solution from OldCurmugedon. I think I'll join it with yours to get an  uber-method for solving all DB-related operations:)